# How to configure Simple Injector to run background threads in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I am using Simple Injector to manage the lifetime of my injected dependencies (in this case `UnitOfWork`), and I am very happy as having a separate decorator rather than my service or command handler looking after saving and disposing makes code a lot easier when writing business logic layers (I follow the architecture that is outlined in [this blog post](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91)).

The above is working perfectly (and very easily) by using the Simple Injector MVC NuGet package and the following code during the construction of the composition root container, if more than one dependency exists in the graph the same instance is injected across all - perfect for Entity Framework model context.

```
private static void InitializeContainer(Container container)
{
    container.RegisterPerWebRequest<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
    // register all other interfaces with:
    // container.Register<Interface, Implementation>();
}
```

I now need to run some background threads and understand from Simple Injector [documentation on threads](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/howto.html#multi-threaded-applications) that commands can be proxied as follows:

```
public sealed class TransactionCommandHandlerDecorator<TCommand>
    : ICommandHandler<TCommand>
{
    private readonly ICommandHandler<TCommand> handlerToCall;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;

    public TransactionCommandHandlerDecorator(
        IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, 
        ICommandHandler<TCommand> decorated)
    {
        this.handlerToCall = decorated;
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public void Handle(TCommand command)
    {
         this.handlerToCall.Handle(command);
         unitOfWork.Save();
    }
}
```

ThreadedCommandHandlerProxy:

```
public class ThreadedCommandHandlerProxy<TCommand>
    : ICommandHandler<TCommand>
{
    Func<ICommandHandler<TCommand>> instanceCreator;

    public ThreadedCommandHandlerProxy(
        Func<ICommandHandler<TCommand>> creator)
    {
        this.instanceCreator = creator;
    }

    public void Handle(TCommand command)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var handler = this.instanceCreator();
            handler.Handle(command);
        });
    }
}
```

However, from this threading sample documentation I can see factories are used, if I introduce factories to my commands and service layer things will get confused and inconsistent as I will have different saving methodologies for different services (one container handles saving, other instantiated factories within services handle saves and disposing) - you can see how clear and simple the service code skeleton is without any factories:

```
public class BusinessUnitCommandHandlers :
    ICommandHandler<AddBusinessUnitCommand>,
    ICommandHandler<DeleteBusinessUnitCommand>
{
    private IBusinessUnitService businessUnitService;
    private IInvoiceService invoiceService;

    public BusinessUnitCommandHandlers(
        IBusinessUnitService businessUnitService, 
        IInvoiceService invoiceService)
    {
        this.businessUnitService = businessUnitService;
        this.invoiceService = invoiceService;
    }

    public void Handle(AddBusinessUnitCommand command)
    {
        businessUnitService.AddCompany(command.name);
    }

    public void Handle(DeleteBusinessUnitCommand command)
    {
        invoiceService.DeleteAllInvoicesForCompany(command.ID);
        businessUnitService.DeleteCompany(command.ID);
    }
}

public class BusinessUnitService : IBusinessUnitService
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
    private readonly ILogger logger;

    public BusinessUnitService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, 
        ILogger logger)
    {
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    void IBusinessUnitService.AddCompany(string name)
    {
        // snip... let container call IUnitOfWork.Save()
    }

    void IBusinessUnitService.DeleteCompany(int ID)
    {
        // snip... let container call IUnitOfWork.Save()
    }
}

public class InvoiceService : IInvoiceService
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
    private readonly ILogger logger;

    public BusinessUnitService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, 
        ILogger logger)
    {
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    void IInvoiceService.DeleteAllInvoicesForCompany(int ID)
    {
        // snip... let container call IUnitOfWork.Save()
    }
}
```

With the above my problem starts to form, as I understand from the [documentation on ASP .NET PerWebRequest lifetimes](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PerWebRequestExtensionMethod), the following code is used:

```
public T GetInstance()
{
    var context = HttpContext.Current;

    if (context == null)
    {
        // No HttpContext: Let's create a transient object.
        return this.instanceCreator();
    }

    object key = this.GetType();
    T instance = (T)context.Items[key];

    if (instance == null)
    {
        context.Items[key] = instance = this.instanceCreator();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

The above works fine for each HTTP request there will be a valid `HttpContext.Current`, however if I spin-up a new thread with the `ThreadedCommandHandlerProxy` it will create a new thread and the `HttpContext` will no longer exist within that thread.

Since the `HttpContext` would be null on each subsequent call, all instances of objects injected into service constructors would be new and unique, the opposite to normal HTTP per web request where objects are shared correctly as the same instance across all services.

So to summarize the above into questions:

How would I go about getting the objects constructed and common items injected regardless of whether created from HTTP request or via a new thread?

Are there any special considerations for having a `UnitOfWork` managed by a thread within a command handler proxy? How can one ensure it is saved and disposed of after the handler has executed?

If we had a problem within the command-handler/service-layer and didn't want to save the `UnitOfWork`, would we simply throw an exception? If so, is it possible to catch this at a global level or do we need to catch the exception per request from within a `try`-`catch` in the handler decorator or proxy?

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: @Steven thanks, I have gone through that question however I'm not 100% sure on what I should do with the RegisterPerWebRequest<DbContext, MyDbContext> and RegisterLifetimeScope<IObjectContextAdapter,MyDbContext> for my case of IUnitOfWork and UnitOfWork, in my case would DbContext => UnitOfWorkBase, MyDbContext => UnitOfWork and IObjectContextAdapter => IUnitOfWork? If you could clarify would be appreciated. Also its mentioned there are a number of ways to do this, is one way to make an explicit lifetime extension for this? Would be nice if didnt have to derive from base classs.

Comment: With the new `async` ActionResults for MVC5, this problem is going to be a common one.

Comment: If the unit of work is a long running and important task consider a message bus "work queue" that you can pick up when your app comes back from a recycle. FYI in reading about `QueueBackgroundWorkItem` I saw that the task will be killed if it takes longer than *90 seconds* so you are at risk if you are taking longer than a minute

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Let me start of by warning that if you wish to execute commands asynchronously in a web application, you might want to take a step back and look at what you are trying to achieve. There is always the risk of the web application being recycled just after you started your handler on a background thread. When a ASP.NET app gets recycled, all background threads will be aborted. It would perhaps be better to publish commands to a (transactional) queue and let a background service pick them up. This ensures that commands can't 'get lost'. And also allows you to re-execute commands when the handler does not succeed successfully. It can also save you from having to do some nasty registrations (which you will probably have no matter which DI framework you pick), but this probably just a side issue. And if you do need to run handlers async, at least try to minimize the number of handlers that you run async.**

With that out of the way, what you need is the following.

As you noted, since you are running (some) command handlers asynchronously, you can't use the per web request lifestyle on them. You will need a hybrid solution, that mixes between per web request and 'something else'. That something else will most likely be a [per lifetime scope](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ObjectLifestyleManagement#PerLifetimeScope). There are no built-in extensions for these hybrid solutions, because of a couple reasons. First of all it's quite an exotic feature that not many people need. Second, you can mix any two or three lifestyles together, so that would be almost an endless combination of hybrids. And last, it is (pretty) easy do register this yourself.

In Simple Injector 2, the `Lifestyle` class has been added and it contains a `CreateHybrid` method that allows combining any two lifestyles to create a new lifestyle. Here's an example:

```
var hybridLifestyle = Lifestyle.CreateHybrid(
    () => HttpContext.Current != null,
    new WebRequestLifestyle(),
    new LifetimeScopeLifestyle());
```

You can use this hybrid lifestyle to register the unit of work:

```
container.Register<IUnitOfWork, DiUnitOfWork>(hybridLifestyle);
```

Since you are registering the unit of work as Per Lifetime Scope, you must explicitly create and dispose a Lifetime Scope for a certain thread. The simplest thing to do is to add this to your `ThreadedCommandHandlerProxy`. This is not the most [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) way of doing things, but it is the easiest way for me to show you how to do this.

> If we had a problem within the command-handler/service-layer and
>   didn't want to save the UnitOfWork, would we simply throw an
>   exception?

The typical thing to do is to throw an exception. It's in fact the general rule of exceptions:

> If your method can't do what it's name promises it can, throw. [->](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IfYourMethodCantDoWhatItsNamePromisesItCanThrow.aspx)

The command handler should be ignorant about how the context in which it is executed, and the last thing you want is to differentiate in whether it should throw an exception. So throwing is your best option. When running on a background thread however, you'd better catch that exception, since .NET will kill the whole AppDomain, if you don't catch it. In a web application this means a AppDomain recycle, which means you're web application (or at least that server) will be offline for a short period of time.

On the other hand, you also don't want to lose any exception information, so you should log that exception, and probably want to log a serialized representation of that command with that exception, so you can see what data was passed in. When added to the `ThreadedCommandHandlerProxy.Handle` method, the it would look like this:

```
public void Handle(TCommand command)
{
    string xml = this.commandSerializer.ToXml(command);    

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        var logger = 
            this.container.GetInstance<ILogger>();

        try
        {
            using (container.BeginTransactionScope())
            {
                // must be created INSIDE the scope.
                var handler = this.instanceCreator();
                handler.Handle(command);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Don't let the exception bubble up, 
            // because we run in a background thread.
            this.logger.Log(ex, xml);
        }
    });
}
```

I warned about how running handlers asynchronously might not be the best idea. However, since you are applying this command / handler pattern, you will be able to switch to using queuing later on, without having to alter a single line of code in your application. It's just a matter of writing some sort of `QueueCommandHandlerDecorator<T>` (which serializes the command and sends it to the queue) and change the way things are wired in your composition root, and you're good to go (and of course don't forget to implement the service that executes commands from the queue). In other words, what's great about this SOLID design is that implementing these features is constant to the size of the application.

Comment: Thanks Steven, your comment on having a background service run everything may be exactly what i am looking for without any other issue of concerns about threads or registration - by 'service' just to clarify could we have the QueueCommandHandlerDecorator write the job to the database (or a WCF web service, or some other inter-process communication method), and have an entirely seperate process (write a second program as a windows service or WCF service) running that picks these job requests up and processes them? Thanks for the great insight into design and avoiding pitfalls.

Comment: @g18c: You can use whatever queue you like best (database, MSMQ), and you can write to your queue in any way you like (directly from within the MVC, or let a WCF service write to the queue), but for picking commands from the queue and executing them, it would be best to use a Windows Service. Or at least, don't use a web service, since in that case you'll face the same problems with app domain recycling as you are already having with your web application. Web services are not meant do deal with background processing. They are for handling requests. Good luck.

Comment: Great stuff, in addition to my existing MVC app I will use my common service/contracts class library with a new windows service that registers required commands in a Simple Injector container (with per thread or perlifetime scope) - since database access is transactional and handled by the container I can easily queue tasks in a jobs to run table without worry of race conditions as the service can poll this table for new records. This design methodology is very powerful as the services are instantly useable regardless of MVC app or Windows Service - many thanks greatly appreciate it.

Comment: One note of warning. When you use a database table as command queue, it is very tricky to implement this transactionally correct when having multiple threads or multiple Windows services processing that single queue. The easiest (safest) thing to do is to have a single threaded windows service processing that queue. Or have a single thread reading/writing to the queue and distributing the commands to other threads that execute the commands. Or have each thread/service operate its own set of commands. This prevents multiple threads/services picking up the same command.

Comment: Not picking this strategy, means you have to use the [UPDLOCK, READPAST](http://www.dwdmbi.com/2010/12/use-updlock-readpast-table-hints-to.html) table hints (which is what we did), but I found out that this model easily breaks (silently) when indexes are added to the table, thus giving you a false sense of security.

Answer (score 5):

Part of the [problems of running background threads in ASP.NET can be overcome](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx) with a convenient command handler decorator:

```
public class AspNetSafeBackgroundCommandHandlerDecorator<T>
    : ICommandHandler<T>, IRegisteredObject
{
    private readonly ICommandHandler<T> decorated;

    private readonly object locker = new object();

    public AspNetSafeBackgroundCommandHandlerDecorator(
        ICommandHandler<T> decorated)
    {
        this.decorated = decorated;
    }

    public void Handle(T command)
    {
        HostingEnvironment.RegisterObject(this);

        try
        {
            lock (this.locker)
            {
                this.decorated.Handle(command);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            HostingEnvironment.UnregisterObject(this);
        }            
    }

    void IRegisteredObject.Stop(bool immediate)
    {
        // Ensure waiting till Handler finished.
        lock (this.locker) { }
    }
}
```

When you put this decorator between a command handler and the `ThreadedCommandHandlerProxy`, you'll ensure that (under normal conditions) AppDomain isn't unloaded while such command is running.