# Castle windsor lifestyle issue

Tags: castle-windsor, ioc-container, castle-windsor-3

I am implementing hangFire which is a job scheduling library in my project.

I am facing the same issue as faced in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873905/castle-windsor-lifestyle-depending-on-context.)

However after replacing `LifestylePerWebRequest()` with `HybridPerWebRequestTransient()` I am still getting the same error message:

> HttpContext.Current is null. PerWebRequestLifestyle can only be used in ASP.Net

Here's a couple of the lines of my dependency installer:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IApiHra>()
                            .ImplementedBy(typeof(ApiHra))
                            .LifeStyle.HybridPerWebRequestTransient()
                            .IsFallback());

container.Register(Component.For<IApiHraComment>()
                            .ImplementedBy(typeof(ApiHraComment))
                            .LifestylePerWebRequest()
                            .IsFallback());
```

This is controller installer in windsor controller factory

```
public class ControllersInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
                                  .BasedOn<IController>()
                                  .LifestyleTransient());
    }
}
```

Please let me know if any other information is required.

Comment: It seems to me that IApiHraComment still has LifestylePerWebRequest. So if this this components is resolved from the container without Http.Context I expect it to throw. Can you find in the error message which component is  causing the exception ?

Comment: actually I am using `IApiHra` only . It has other dependencies as well, i tried making them all hybrid but it did not work.`IApiHra` is causing the exception

Comment: @SJMan Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Any solution for this? I am struggling with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

See Krzysztof Kozmic's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41254172/1062614). Your `IApiHra` component likely has a `PerWebRequestLifestyle` dependency.