# Transient Lifestyle requires HttpContext?

Tags: httpwebrequest, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I am registering my component like this:

```
public static void Register(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
    container.Register(Classes.FromAssembly(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(GenericBaseRepository)))
        .InSameNamespaceAs<GenericBaseRepository>()
        .WithService.DefaultInterfaces()
        .LifestyleTransient());
    }
```

I am then resolving it in a piece of code that has no HttpContext:

```
var baseRepository = ContainerManager.Container.Resolve<IBaseRepository>();
```

(IBaseRepository being an interface implemented by GenericBaseRepository). This fails with the following message:

**"HttpContext.Current is null. PerWebRequestLifestyle can only be used in ASP.Net"**

Which confuses me, because the lifestyle I choose is Transient, not PerWebRequest.
Of course, HttpContext doesn't exist during a scheduled task - but I don't really need it, I just want an instance of my Repository which will not interact with any web request.

So, why does Castle Windsor insist in requiring an HttpContext when resolving my component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the full exception message. Your root component may be transient but the exception indicates one of its dependencies uses per web request lifestyle.

Have a look at Windsor's [diagnostics debugger view](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/debugger-views.md), that may help you pinpoint it.

Comment: Yes, this was indeed the case. After struggling to get the right .pdb for Castle Core/Windsor and (managing to step into the code), this was the culprit.