# Abstract Factory with parameter using DI Container

Tags: c#, abstract-factory, di-containers

I have an interface called `IService` and derived services like `IServiceA : IService`, `IServiceB : IService`, `IServiceC : IService`, etc.
The implementation classes of those services needs a context parameter of type `MyContext`, and some services will need a refernece to other services in that context. for example:
`ServiceA : IServiceA` needs `MyContext` and `IServiceC` (in constructor).
ServiceB : IServiceB only needs `MyContext`.

- I want to create an abstract factory that will create every service
  upon request. something like:

  `T GetService<T>(/*MyContext context - ?*/) where T : IService;`

  but i don't quite know how to add the context part.
  I understand that the MyContext parameter is part of the implementation details of every service, so I'll be happy to hear
  about different ways to solve this problem.
- I also need a way to create those services according to their context
  value, so that for example multiple requests to create `IServiceA`
  with the same `MyContext` parameter will return the same instance of
  IServiceA and if a request for `IServiceA` with different `MyContext`
  parameter will return a different instance.
- Finally, I need a way to integrate it with a DI Container (Castle
  Windsor preferred) so that the creation and the context handling will
  occur close to the application root.

Thanks

Comment: Nice requirments, but we are not here to write code instead of you. Show some code and exact problem !

Comment: Why do you need an abstract factory for this? All constructor parameters are injectables. Just inject them via the constructor, setup the registrations, and you're done.

Comment: I think he want to create context dependent singletons (one instance per context).

Comment: If you want different instances for certain circumstances is a **lifestyle/scoping** issue. Register your component with the correct scope/lifestyle, and it will solve itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Castle.Windsor lifestyle depending on context?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873905/castle-windsor-lifestyle-depending-on-context)

Comment: @mybirthname I know you are not here to write code instead of me, there isn't code here anyway, only an idea of implementation. I chose not to include the services implementation because i think it is irrelevant to the problem and i prefer not to add redundant code here.  @eocron06 yes i need context dependent singleton my problem is how to use it with the `MyContext` parameter And I don't believe it is duplicate,I read the answer about Hybrid lifestyle, I need something similar but not exaclty the same,there the use of it is especially for WebRequests for ThreadStatic Resources, here I don't.

Comment: @Maarten how can I register my components in this way? Do you have any link I can use to accomplish that?

Comment: Have a look at [Factory method with DI and Ioc](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31971691/181087).

Comment: I've ended up using a mixture of solutions (DI container's scope accessor and a custom scope). I will post a proper answer, I just didn't had time to provide my solution as a proper answer. But NightOwl888 the Link you provided is also a great suggestion with a mixture of the custom scope (for the context parameter),I will add it to the answer as well. Thanks.