# Mixed lifestyle for Per Thread and Per Web Request with Simple Injector

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, simple-injector

I'm using `SimpleInjector` as my IoC library. I register `DbContext` as per web request and it works fine. But there is one task that I run it in a background thread. So, I have a problem to create `DbContext` instances. e.g.

1. `Service1` has an instance of `DbContext`
2. `Service2` has an instance of `DbContext`
3. `Service1` and `Service2` run from background thread.
4. `Service1` fetches an entity and pass it to `Service2`
5. `Service2` uses that entity, but entity is detached from `DbContext`

Actually the problem is here: `Service1.DbContext` is difference from `Service2.DbContext`.

It seems when I run a task in a separate thread in ASP.NET MVC, `SimpleInjector` creates a new instance of `DbContext` for each call. While some IoC libraries (for example `StructureMap`) have a mixed lifestyle for per-thread-per-webrequest, it seems `SimpleInjector` hasn't one. Am I right?

Have you any idea to solve this problem in `SimpleInjector`?
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

My services are here:

```
class Service1 : IService1 {
    public Service1(MyDbContext context) { }
}

class Service2 : IService2 {
    public Service2(MyDbContext context, IService1 service1) { }
}

class SyncServiceUsage {
    public SyncServiceUsage(Service2 service2) {
        // use Service2 (and Service1 and DbContext) from HttpContext.Current
    }
}

class AsyncServiceUsage {
    public AsyncServiceUsage(Service2 service2) {
        // use Service2 (and Service1 and DbContext) from background thread
    }
}

public class AsyncCommandHandlerDecorator<TCommand> 
    : ICommandHandler<TCommand> where TCommand : ICommand {

    private readonly Func<ICommandHandler<TCommand>> _factory;

    public AsyncCommandHandlerDecorator(Func<ICommandHandler<TCommand>> factory) {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public void Handle(TCommand command) {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => {
            // Create new handler in this thread.
            var handler = _factory();
            handler.Handle(command);
        });
    }
}

void InitializeSimpleInjector() {
    register AsyncCommandHandlerDecorator for services (commands actually) that starts with "Async"
}
```

I user `Service2` sometimes and `AsyncService2` other times.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041601/simple-injector-multi-threading-in-mvc3-asp-net

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10304023/simpleinjector-is-this-the-right-way-to-registermanyforopengeneric-when-i-have

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> It seems when I run a task in a separate thread in ASP.NET MVC,
>   SimpleInjector creates a new instance of DbContext for each call.

The behavior of the `RegisterPerWebRequest` lifestyle of Simple Injector v1.5 and below is to return a transient instance when instances are requested outside the context of a web request (where `HttpContext.Current` is null). Returning a transient instance was a design flaw in Simple Injector, since this makes it easy to hide improper usage. [Version 1.6 of the Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/releases/view/97655) will throw an exception instead of incorrectly returning a transient instance, to communicate clearly that you have mis-configured the container.

> While some IoC libraries (for example StructureMap) have a mixed
>   lifestyle for per-thread-per-webrequest, it seems Simple Injector
>   hasn't one

It is correct that Simple Injector has no built-in support for mixed lifestyles because of a couple reasons. First of all it's quite an exotic feature that not many people need. Second, you can mix any two or three lifestyles together, so that would be almost an endless combination of hybrids. And last, it is (pretty) easy do register this yourself.

Although you can mix [Per Web Request](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/lifetimes.html#perwebrequest) with [Per Thread](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/lifetimes.html#perthread) lifestyles, it would probably be better when you mix Per Web Request with [Per Lifetime Scope](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/lifetimes.html#perlifetimescope), since with the Lifetime Scope you explicitly start and finish the scope (and can dispose the `DbContext` when the scope ends).

From [Simple Injector 2](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/releases/view/99008) and on, you can easily mix any number of lifestyles together using the [Lifestyle.CreateHybrid](https://simpleinjector.org/ReferenceLibrary/?topic=html/M_SimpleInjector_Lifestyle_CreateHybrid.htm) method. Here is an example:

```cs
var hybridLifestyle = Lifestyle.CreateHybrid(
    () => HttpContext.Current != null,
    new WebRequestLifestyle(),
    new LifetimeScopeLifestyle());

// Register as hybrid PerWebRequest / PerLifetimeScope.
container.Register<DbContext, MyDbContext>(hybridLifestyle);
```

There is another Stackoverflow question that goes into this subject a bit deeper, you might want to take a look: [Simple Injector: multi-threading in MVC3 ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041601/simple-injector-multi-threading-in-mvc3-asp-net)

**UPDATE**

About your update. You are almost there. The commands that run on a background thread need to run within a *Lifetime Scope*, so you will have to start it explicitly. The trick here is to call `BeginLifetimeScope` on the new thread, but before the actual command handler (and its dependencies) is created. In other words, the best way to do this is inside a decorator.

The easiest solution is to update your `AsyncCommandHandlerDecorator` to add the scope:

```cs
public class AsyncCommandHandlerDecorator<TCommand> 
    : ICommandHandler<TCommand> where TCommand : ICommand 
{
    private readonly Container _container;
    private readonly Func<ICommandHandler<TCommand>> _factory;

    public AsyncCommandHandlerDecorator(Container container,
        Func<ICommandHandler<TCommand>> factory) 
    {
        _container = container;
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public void Handle(TCommand command) 
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => 
        {
            using (_container.BeginLifetimeScope())
            {
                // Create new handler in this thread
                // and inside the lifetime scope.
                var handler = _factory();
                handler.Handle(command);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Purists that advocate the [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) principles will shout that this class is violating the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), since this decorator both runs commands on a new thread and starts a new lifetime scope. I wouldn't worry much about this, since I think that there is a close relationship between starting a background thread and starting a lifetime scope (you wouldn't use one without the other anyway). But still, you could easily leave the `AsyncCommandHandlerDecorator` untouched and create a new `LifetimeScopedCommandHandlerDecorator` as follows:

```cs
public class LifetimeScopedCommandHandlerDecorator<TCommand> 
    : ICommandHandler<TCommand> where TCommand : ICommand 
{
    private readonly Container _container;
    private readonly Func<ICommandHandler<TCommand>> _factory;

    public LifetimeScopedCommandHandlerDecorator(Container container,
        Func<ICommandHandler<TCommand>> factory)
    {
        _container = container;
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public void Handle(TCommand command)
    {
        using (_container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            // The handler must be created inside the lifetime scope.
            var handler = _factory();
            handler.Handle(command);
        }
    }
}
```

The order in which these decorators are registered is of course essential, since the `AsyncCommandHandlerDecorator` **must** wrap the `LifetimeScopedCommandHandlerDecorator`. This means that the `LifetimeScopedCommandHandlerDecorator` registration must come first:

```cs
container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
    typeof(LifetimeScopedCommandHandlerDecorator<>),
    backgroundCommandCondition);

container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
    typeof(AsyncCommandHandlerDecorator<>),
    backgroundCommandCondition);
```

[This old Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10304023/simpleinjector-is-this-the-right-way-to-registermanyforopengeneric-when-i-have) talks about this in more detail. You should definitely take a look.

Comment: Thanks +Steven I read the other link and its useful and helpful. Also, I voted up the answer and question all, to improve `SimpleInjector` reputation. Good luck

Comment: WTF I confused! I edit my question. Can you please tell me about usage? The `Service1` and `Service2` objects, are used in both main thread (web request) and background thread. I want to be able to do this. And I inject `DbContext` to them by ctor injection. Should I change my implementation?

Comment: @Javad_Amiry: I'm sorry for my late reply, but even developers need some rest sometimes ;-). I updated my answer. I hope this helps.