# SimpleInjector and System.Web.Mvc.Async threads

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, simple-injector

I [asked before a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147509/simpleinjector-mixed-lifestyle-for-per-thread-and-per-webrequest) here, and I read this question/answers about multi-threading and I know those solutions. But today I get a new problem. When we are using commands (or where we can access the original code to manage and modify it) the async-decorator that suggested in above answers works. But when MVC creates a new thread itself, what can we do? e.g. I have a custom role provider (works with `DbContext`), and I get this error:

> The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.

And here is stack trace:

> [InvalidOperationException: The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.]
>
> System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CheckContextNotDisposed() +67
>
> System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() +34
>
> System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +22
>
> System.Linq.Queryable.Any(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) +265
>
> ***MyProject.MyRoleProvider.IsUserInRole(String username, String roleName) in ...***
>
> System.Web.Security.Roles.IsUserInRole(String username, String roleName) +263
>
> MyProject.MyPrincipal.IsInRole(String role) in ...
>
> System.Linq.Enumerable.Any(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) +146
>
> System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute.AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext) +200
>
> System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) +159
>
> System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +96
>
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.***<>c__DisplayClass25.b__1e***(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +446
>
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.***WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin***(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +130
>
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.***AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction***(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +302
>
> System.Web.Mvc.***<>c__DisplayClass1d.b__17***(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +30
>
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.***WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin***(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +130
>
> System.Web.Mvc.***Controller.BeginExecuteCore***(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +382
>
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.***WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin***(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +130
>
> System.Web.Mvc.***Controller.BeginExecute***(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +317
>
> System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.***IAsyncController.BeginExecute***(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +15
>
> System.Web.Mvc.***<>c__DisplayClass8.b__2***(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +71
>
> System.Web.Mvc.Async.***WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin***(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +130
>
> System.Web.Mvc.***MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest***(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +249
>
> System.Web.Mvc.***MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest***(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +50
>
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.***IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest***(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
>
> System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +301
>
> System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

As you can see, `MyProject.MyRoleProvider.IsUserInRole` invoked asynchronously, which I did not start it and its invoking async by MVC itself. So I have not any control on it. My provider ctor is:

public MyRoleProvider() {
    _context = MyIoCWrapper.GetService();
}

It seems when `MyRoleProvider` instantiated, `HttpContext` is not null, and when `IsInRole` called, `HttpContext` is null.
If I want to start a new life scope, it will be used just once, and if MVC starts a new thread, I will have a new `DbContext` too. I confused to finding a solution. Have you any one?
How can I start a new life scope for all background threads -I start them or MVC starts them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in fact unrelated to running controllers asynchronously, but is a general problem of controlling the lifetime of objects.

You probably registered your `MyRoleProvider` in the web.config of the application, or perhaps registered it through code. Eitherway, the `MyRoleProvider` is a singleton, there is just a single instance of that class during the lifetime of the application.

The `MyRoleProvider` however depends on a `DbContext` which has a lifestyle that is shorter (Per Web Request or hybrid in your case), which means you can't cache that `DbContext` during the lifetime of your `MyRoleProver`, since that would 'promote' the lifestyle of that `DbContext` to singleton as well. The `_context = MyIoCWrapper.GetService();` line seems to indicate that you are caching that `DbContext`.

In this case you will have to resolve the `DbContext` instance on each method call. So instead, your `IsUserInRole` would look something like this:

```
public bool IsUserInRole(String username, String roleName)
{
    var context = MyIoCWrapper.GetService();
    return context.Roles
        .Any(r => r.Name == roleName && r.User.Name == username);
}
```

Comment: OSh!!!! yes yes yes you are right. I forgot that Providers are singleton ): sorry about an unrelated question. I made it difficult to myself, while it was a simple and plain situation