# How to ensure that all task are executed before DI controller is disposed

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, dispose

I'm using dependency injection to inject controllers in my web app.

What I'm want to do is execute my logic in a try catch statement and if at somepoint the logic fails and throws an exception I'll save it to logs in my database.

I was hoping to achieve this using Task.Run so I would not have to wait for log saving process and return data immediately to my blazor app.

the problem rises at this point, as soon as the method is executed the service is disposed and logs are never saved to database as my dbcontext is disposed among with it..

so I was hoping if it is possible to ensure that the task is executed before disposing it or there is any other workound to achieve this.

```
 public async ValueTask<RESPONSE_RESULT<string>> SomeMethod(CallContext context = default)
    {
         try
         { //Execute some logic}
         catch
         {
            //add logs to database in a different thread
             Task.Run( async ()=> {  //My logic here to add code to database  } );
         }
         Return default;
    }
```

but

Comment: teek a reference to the tasks, `await` them in your Dispose-method? although an exception-logging middleware seems the smarter way to achieve your goal. or a logging-service with longer lifetime. or a db-provider for `ILogger`

Comment: Mediator pattern where the services pass the logging responsibility off to a hostedservice  with a queue to log messages it receives. it will have its own access to db for its lifetime so no issues with disposal.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#queued-background-tasks-1

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13982600/using-dependencies-on-multiple-threads-with-parallel-foreach

Comment: @Nkosi, this is interesting. Just a quick question though as I don't have the opportunity to give it a try now, the example given in the link registers services.AddSingleton<MonitorLoop>(); and hostedservice is injected to MonitorLoop Constructor.
will it still work with even if I register the service as scoped?

Comment: @AsımGündüz That `MonitorLoop` being registered as singleton was specific to that example. `MonitorLoop` in that example was the client passing tasks to the queue. You controller will be the client sending tasks to the queue to be executed in the background.

Comment: @Nkosi the documentation you have provided worked perfectly, thanks

Comment: @AsımGündüz glad everything worked out. Happy coding!!!

Comment: @AsımGündüz you should also add it as a self answer for what worked for you so that others can benefit from it in the future. I am curious how you implemented your solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you need your context (either scoped or transient) inside `Task.Run` use `IServiceScopeFactory`:

```
using (var scope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
{
    //use context now
    var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MyContext>();
}
```

The calling method should pass in the instance of the service scope factory