# Decorating interfaces of different lifestyles

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I use Simple Injector as my IoC container. SimpleInjector uses [this simple technique to handle mixed life style for Per Thread and Per Web Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147509/mixed-lifestyle-for-per-thread-and-per-web-request-with-simple-injector)

```
container.RegisterPerWebRequest<IWebUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
container.RegisterLifetimeScope<IThreadUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
container.Register<IUnitOfWork>(() => container.GetInstance<UnitOfWork>());

// Register as hybrid PerWebRequest / PerLifetimeScope.
container.Register<UnitOfWork>(() =>
{
    if (HttpContext.Current != null)
        return container.GetInstance<IWebUnitOfWork>() as UnitOfWork;
    else
        return container.GetInstance<IThreadUnitOfWork>() as UnitOfWork;
});
```

I wish to decorate the interface `IUnitOfWork` with classes such as `UnitOfWorkAuthoriseDecorator`, `UnitOfWorkExceptionDecorator` & `UnitOfWorkTraceDecorator`. 
What should I decorate?

- `IUnitOfWork`
- `IWebUnitOfWork` & `IThreadUnitOfWork`
- `IUnitOfWork` & `IWebUnitOfWork` & `IThreadUnitOfWork`
- `UnitOfWork`
- something else

Comment: btw, are you sure that you're intercepting/decorating at the right abstraction level? It find it quite unusual to decorate a unit of work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems most intuitive to me to decorate the `IUnitOfWork` instance:

```
container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(IUnitOfWork),
    typeof(UnitOfWorkAuthoriseDecorator));

container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(IUnitOfWork),
    typeof(UnitOfWorkExceptionDecorator));

container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(IUnitOfWork),
    typeof(UnitOfWorkTraceDecorator));
```

Decorating anything else would probably be rather awkward, since when decorating multiple interfaces, you need to have a decorator per interface (and in your case 3 decorators per interface).

Decorating the `UnitOfWork` class is possible, but probably very inconvenient, since you will have to make all members of this class virtual and override them in the decorators, since those decorators need to inherit from `UnitOfWork`.

Comment: Thanks Steven, I was looking for confirmation that decorating IUnitOfWork would be enough as it seemed to me to be the neatest option.