# Registering instances with mixed per-request/per-thread/per-task lifestyle

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, dependency-injection, ioc-container

We're applying the Dependency Injection pattern in my application and I have some components that need to be cached per request, thread or task. We want to be able to start tasks/threads and each task/thread should use its own `DbContext`. Each HTTP request needs its own `DbContext` as well.

How can we configure and implement this behavior? I accept examples for any common IoC-container.

Comment: That seems to me as a basic functionality of any IoC. I am using simple injector for same goals you mentioned

Comment: Really any IoC container will accomplish this. I prefer SimpleInjector or Autofac.

Comment: As others mentioned, any decent IoC can accomplish what you need. I'd recommend Unity since it's very popular with MVC apps, but I've used Autofac or Ninject successfully as well. I believe this is opinion based

Comment: Do note that caching instances [per thread is a REALLY BAD idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591422/why-is-perthreadlifetimemanager-used-in-this-example/14592419#14592419)!

Comment: TinyIoC. Now that you have 5 different people, all giving you conflicting answers, how do you feel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think almost any DI library will do in this case, since almost all of them have out-of-the-box support for scoped lifestyles. Since you request some specific examples, I can show you how to do this with [Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.org).

In Simple Injector, caching instances during the lifetime of a web request is a matter of using the `WebRequestLifestyle` or one of the `RegisterPerWebRequest` extension methods. Example:

```
container.RegisterPerWebRequest<MyEntities>(() => new MyEntities("some conn.str"));
```

This is of course a very basic scenario, but what you are describing is a more interesting, since you are spinning of background tasks and each task should run in its own context. In this case you will have to explicitly define a scope in which you resolve instances; you can't do this implicitly (as you can when running in the context of a web request). This is independent of the framework you use.

With Simple Injector it depends a bit on how those background operations run. If they are single-threaded, you can use the [LifetimeScopeLifestyle](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/lifetimes.html#per-lifetime-scope). If that task is asynchronous (using the new asynchronous async/await programming model of C#), you can use the [ExecutionScopeLifestyle](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/lifetimes.html#per-execution-context-scope).

But let's assume that operation is single-threaded. As I said, for each operation, you will have to explicitly start a scope from which object graphs are resolved. Example:

```
using (container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
    // Resolve within the context of the scope:
    var processor = container.GetInstance<IRequestProcessor>();

    processor.Process(request);
}
```

In this case however, because there is no web request, you need to configure your scoped objects differently:

```
container.RegisterLifetimeScope<MyEntities>(() => new MyEntities("some conn.str"));
```

When you however want to run those operations in the same app domain as you run the web application itself, you will need to use a [hybrid lifestyle](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/lifetimes.html#hybrid). Here's how to do it:

```
var scopedLifestyle = Lifestyle.CreateHybrid(
    lifestyleSelector: () => HttpContext.Current != null,
    trueLifestyle: new WebRequestLifestyle(),
    falseLifestyle: new LifetimeScopeLifestyle());

container.Register<MyEntities>(() => new MyEntities("some conn.str"), scopedLifestyle);
container.Register<IRepository<User>, UserRepository>(scopedLifestyle);
// etc
```

Best practice however is to prevent the application from taking a dependency on the container. So the last thing you want to do is to have calls to `container.BeginLifetimeScope()` and `container.GetInstance<T>` spread throughout the whole application.

Instead this logic should be centralized in a single place called the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/). A great way to allow your web request code to spin up background operations, while both sides to stay oblivious of this fact is by using decorator. Say for instance your MVC controllers execute business operations and some of them must be executed asynchronously.

Say for instance you have some `IRequestProcessor<TRequest>` abstraction that should execute those requests. You can create the following decorator for this and place it inside your composition root:

```
public class LifetimeScopeRequestProcessorDecorator<TRequest> 
    : IRequestProcessor<TRequest>
{
    private readonly Container container;
    private readonly Func<IRequestProcessor<TRequest>> decorateeFactory;

    public LifetimeScopeRequestProcessorDecorator(Container container,
        Func<IRequestProcessor<TRequest>> decorateeFactory)
    {
        this.container = container;
        this.decorateeFactory = decorateeFactory;
    }

    public void Handle(TRequest request)
    {
        using (this.container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            IRequestProcessor<TRequest> processor = this.decoratorFactory.Invoke();

            processor.Handle(request);
        }
    }
}
```

Now this decorator can be wrapped around any request processor implementation. The injected `Func<IRequestProcessor<TRequest>>` allows a new request processor instance to be resolved, while the `BeginLifetimeScope` again ensures that the operation is executed in the context of such scope. With Simple Injector you register the decorator as follows:

```
 // using SimpleInjector.Extensions;
container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(IRequestProcessor<>),
    typeof(LifetimeScopeRequestProcessorDecorator<>));
```

Now both the controller and the processor themselves know nothing about this, and by creating a decorator and registering it, you prevented having to make any sweeping changes throughout the application. You can read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041601/how-to-configure-simple-injector-to-run-background-threads-in-asp-net-mvc) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13147509/mixed-lifestyle-for-per-thread-and-per-web-request-with-simple-injector) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10304023/simpleinjector-is-this-the-right-way-to-registermanyforopengeneric-when-i-have).

If however only part of your request processors run in the background, you can easily do this conditionally, for instance by letting your commands implement an interface and place a generic type constraint on your `LifetimeScopeRequestProcessorDecorator<T>`. Simple Injector will pick that up automatically. Otherwise, if you want to do it based on some attribute, you can register the decorator using a predicate as follows:

```
container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(IRequestProcessor<>),
    typeof(LifetimeScopeRequestProcessorDecorator<>), 
        c => c.ImplementationType.GetCustomAttribute<AsyncAttribute>() != null);
```